# Sync User Keycloack with User spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

Hello I'm on a spring boot application with a keycloak authentication server and I would like to save the users on the spring database does anyone have a track to help me thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean, users will register themselves on Keycloak and it will also be stored in spring application database as well?

Comment: Yes I would like that when the user registers it is automatically registered on springboot application

Answer (score 0):

You can listen when a user is created successfully using [EventiListener spi](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events)

Code sample that is only executed only when the transaction is successful:

```java
public class MyEventListenerProvider implements EventListenerProvider {
  private EventListenerTransaction tx = new EventListenerTransaction(this::processAdminEvent,this::processEvent);
  @Override
  public void onEvent(Event event) {
    tx.addEvent(event);
  }
  @Override
  public void onEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean includeRepresentation) {
    tx.addAdminEvent(adminEvent, includeRepresentation);
  }
  private void processAdminEvent(AdminEvent adminEvent, boolean includeRepresentation) {
  // Do whatever you want with the admin event
  }
  private void processEvent(Event event) {
  // Do whatever you want with the event
  }
}
```

Comment: where does that go?
On the resource spring boot or on the keycloak side?